# Python - No result from timeit

Tags: python, timeit

I wrote this simple code (in python) in test.py. I try to run timeit and I don't have any errors but I don't get any information about the time of run. Can you help me ?

```
import timeit

def functionsWhile():
    "Desc about function"
    lic = 0
    n = 30000
    while lic<= n:
            lic += 1
    #print "test"
    return lic

t = timeit.Timer("functionsWhile()", "from __main__ import functionsWhile")

try:
    t.repeat(3, 2)
except:
    t.print_exc()
```

I expect a result such as (EXAMPLE):

```
$>python test.py
[0.006793975830078125, 0.006793975830078125, 0.006793975830078125]
$>
```

But I have only:

```
$>python test.py
$>
```

I don't have result from timeit. I use python 2.7 and linux.

Comment: Yeah, just typing the variable name only works in the interactive interpreter but not when run as a script.

Comment: "just typing the variable name only works in the interactive interpreter but not when run as a script." That's how the interpreter works for _everything_ that returns a value. Try putting a plain "Hello" in the interactive interpreter and in a script, for example.

Comment: Your code is giving the desired `output` in python interpreter.So, you are definitely missing a `print` statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to `print` the result of `t.repeat`.