# %%timeit not returning defined variable

Tags: python, ipython, timeit

I'm trying to use IPython magic command `%%timeit` and I run into some problems. The chunk that I'm trying to time is not returning a variable I define in it.

Specifically, let's say I want to measure how long does it take to set variable var to 30.

```
%%timeit
var = 5 * 6
```

Running this chunk, I get something like `16.8 ns ± 0.303 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)`. When I later try to call var, I get `NameError: name 'var' is not defined`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471897/python-no-result-from-timeit) question, however, I'm not sure what to take from it. Also, it is from 2014 so I think there could have been some changes.

Is there a way how to 'keep' variable defined in a chunk with `%%timeit` so that it can be later called?

I'm using Python 3.6, Anaconda 4.4.10.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5767.

Comment: After reading through the issue, I assume that there is no simple solution and I should simply abandon the idea of doing this. Thanks for the link!

Comment: A recent question like this [timing in python with %timeit %%timeit how to keep/retain values for later use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769703/timing-in-python-with-timeit-timeit-how-to-keep-retain-values-for-later-use)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565829/simple-way-to-measure-cell-execution-time-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: If you're okay with only running it once, you can use `%%time` instead of `%%timeit`. `%%time` has been changed within the past year or so to remember variables.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `%%time` cell magic instead (or the `%time` line magic)

```
%time var = 5 * 6
# CPU times: user 2 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 2 µs
# Wall time: 3.81 µs

var
# Out: 30
```

I guess the reason why variables are not remembered by `%timeit` is that it's a series of experiments--when experimenting one should always assume that something might go wrong, so it's not clear what the valid variable instantiation should be.

To see what kind of repeated runs `%%timeit` performs, check also [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71474768/2314737).